# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

After receiving items, the following error occurs.
At the moment I'm just learning and have looked at other answers on this topic, nothing comes up.

```
export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://62fa26ddffd7197707e66da8.mockapi.io/items')
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setItems(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        Alert.alert('Ошибка', 'Ошибка при получении статей');
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar style="inverted" />
      {items.map((obj) => (
        <Post title={obj.title} price={obj.price} imageUrl={obj.imageUrl} />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Error:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.map')

This error is located at:
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)
```

Comment: have you tried logging out what items is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items` default value is not an array, you just need to set blank array as default.

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I put ' ', I thought that an empty value is required, but here is an array! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that first render will be with your default state in `useState`. So you need write a condition or pass valid default value in `useState` like empty array

Comment: Yes, you're right, I'll take that into account, thanks!